# Как воспроизвести на другом компьютере Google Chrome сессии?

Tags: google-chrome, сессия, безопасность, взлом

Google Chrome хранит пароли,закладки, куки здесь

```
c:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\
```

У FireFox своя папка.
При копировании папки FireFox на другой компьютер можно дальше продолжить работать под тем же аккаунтом.
Однако Chrome шифрует и простое копирование папки на другой компьютер ничего не даёт.
Есть ли какая-то программа, которая отслеживает определённую программу(например Google Chrome) для того,что бы узнать- какие запросы делает та программа?
Я пока только Process Monitor нашёл для этого.

**Как перенести все пользовательские данные Google Chrome на другой компьютер, не прибегая к синхронизации аккаунта?**

**Что нужно сделать, что б скопировать все сессии Google Chrome на другой компьютер и что б все сайты, пароли, закладки и текущие сессии открылись на другом компьютере и воссоздать работу на другом компьютере так же, как и на первом??**

Comment: Хром (точнее, хромиум) - open source. Возьмите исходники и посмотрите :)

Comment: @PashaPash ,если б я ещё понимал C++ или на чём он там написан?Хотя посмотрю, но я там не разбирусь,что куда((

Answer (score 1):

Создайте аккаунт в браузере и настройте синхронизацию.

Comment: Это понятно.Меня интересует вопрос,что происходит на более низком уровне?Почему,скопировав все файлы пользователя на другой комп-ни сессии,ни пароли не воспроизводятся на том компе.Я по поводу защиты.Она по-видимому привязана к конкретному компу. Вот в мозиле можно скопировать файлы пользовалеля и продолжить работать на др компе под теми же сессиями,а здесь какая-то защита

Comment: Ну, видимо, стоит какая-то привязка к железу/ОС. И это, я считаю, правильно)

Answer (score 0):

Все правильно! Привязка идет к аккаунту. И браузер не хранит важную информацию локально.

Comment: окей. Так вот интересует вариант, как получить данные? что нужно скопировать, что б воссоздать работу на другом компьютере?

Comment: Базу гугла. Интеграция идет даже с адроид устроиствами. Все хранится на серверах

Answer (score -1):

Есть 2 компьютера А и Б. На А компьютере работали, на Б стоит чистый Chrome.

На А я зашел в "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data" и скопировал оттуда папку Default.
На компьютер Б вставил папку Default по такому же пути и перезаписал все файлы.

Все! На компьютере Б у меня открылся точно такой же Chrome как и на А.

Или же он всё таки не такой же?

Comment: вот я так и думал. Теоретически да, а практически ничего на компе Б- нет. В отличие от мозилы, где такой вариант сработал. Ни списка паролей, сайтов истории, ни, например залогиненого вконтакте на компе А или почты.

Comment: @"Николай" Вы именно так и сделали?

Comment: @RakzinRoman, да, Вы правы. Посмотрел сейчас что именно перенеслось и там много чего не хватает. Как только не пробовал, всё равно Chrome сбрасывает настройки по умолчанию. Буду дальше копать)

Answer (score -1):

У меня это получилось копированием двух файлов в папку \User Data\Default\Sessions
Файлы начинаются на Session_nnnnnnnnnnnnn и Tabs_nnnnnnnnnnnnn
При том копировать нужно с изменением старого имени на имя, которое было в новой папке (если их там несколько пар, то выбрать то, которое было последним по времени).
Это касается версии окт-2021